# My generic DetailView not showing list of items

Tags: django, django-views

I am following a django tutorial series, the music website contains the ListView which contains Albums(this is showing) but the DetailView Containing the list of songs in each Album is not showing.

I have tried changing the iteration name in the for loop but it still not working, the list shows when i am not using the generic method i.e using index and detail function instead of the IndexView and DetailView classes.

## MY music.views Code

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name='music/index.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Albums.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Albums
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'
```

## My detail.html code which is supposed to show the list of songs but not working

```
 {% extends 'music/base.html' %}
    {% block title %} Album Details  {% endblock %}
    {% block body %}
            <img src ="{{ all_album.alb_logo }}">
            <h1>{{ all_album.alb_title }}</h1>
            <ul>
            {% for song in all_album.song_set.all %}
            <li>{{ song.song_title }} </li>
            {% endfor %}  
            </ul>    
            <br>
    {% endblock %}
```

## My index.html which shows the list of albums, this is working

```
 {% extends 'music/base.html' %}
    {% block body %}
    <h2>List of Current albums available</h2>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row'>
          {% for album in object_list %}  
            <div class='col-lg-4'>                    
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ album.alb_logo }}" >
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ album.alb_title }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ album.alb_artist }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}" class="btn 
                     btn-primary  btn-sm">View details</a>
                </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
              {% endfor %}
          </div>
      </div>
```

## My urls.py code#

```
 urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    ]
```

The detail.html page is expected to show the list of songs in a selected album that is already in the database when clicked, but it is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the ***wrong context variable name(`all_album`) inside the template, it should be `object`***.

```
#detail.html 
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Album Details  {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <img src="{{ object.alb_logo }}">
    <h1>{{ object.alb_title }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for song in object.song_set.all %}
            <li>{{ song.song_title }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <br>
{% endblock %}
```

**Reference**: [**DetailView `get_context_data()` method**--Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data)

Comment: Hey JPG, you just saved me from leaving coding. Thank you very much, God bless, you dont know how happy I am.

Comment: It's pleasure to hear that. Anyway please do *Accept the answer* if this solved the issue. 